Depcreated API removeImage(forKey:cacheType:completion) for SDWebImage
After updating the SDWebImage Library to 15.9.1 version i am facing with the current deprecated API

What does it mean the following statement: "No longer use. Cast to cache instance and call its API"
The library uses itself an internal NSCache, so it's not very clear to me what this suggestion implies to do, any advices?

It sounds like SDImageCacheType likely has a remove function

It's not longer used by SDWebImage internally, as the definition are in the portion #pragma mark - Deprecated because SDWebImageManager does not use these APIs. The change has been introduced in 5.15.0 in early 2023, so you were quite outdated to see it only now. More infos might be found on the PR changes: https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage/pull/3466 You were using that API yourself (to get the warning), could you show us what you were doing exactly, on which instance? Since there are removeImageFromDiskForKey and removeImageFromMemoryForKey potentially available in SDImageCache

@Larme we were doing the following thing in the codebaseimagesToBeRemovedFromCache.forEach { imageURL in             self.removeImage(forKey: imageURL, cacheType: cacheType, completion: completion)         }
Xcode 15.3 showed the error mentioned above: "No longer use. Cast to cache instance and call its API". I momentarely fixed the error by adding '?' meaning this code but apparently it's not necessary from what i am seeing now.
imagesToBeRemovedFromCache.forEach { imageURL in             self.removeImage?(forKey: imageURL, cacheType: cacheType, completion: completion)         }

@Larme Edit: my mistake i was looking at a different branch, the '?' that we added fixed the error Xcode was displaying but to be honest i didn't understand why it solved. We updated SDWebImage from 5.8.4 to 5.19.1

@Larme this was the other part of the code: var imagesToBeRemovedFromCache: Set = []
